# Cannot retrieve definition for form bean

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I am having the following error in my jsp page :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve definition for form bean myLoginForm
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:535)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)


org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
com.dps.onlineAdmissions.util.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:57)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

My form bean in struts-config.xml is :

```
<form-beam name="myLoginForm" type="com.dps.onlineAdmissions.form.MyLoginForm" />
```

My action tag is :

```
<action type="com.dps.onlineAdmissions.action.MyLogin" path="/MyLogin" 
             name="myLoginForm" validate="true" input="/Index2.jsp" scope="request">

        <forward name="newUser" path="/welcome.jsp" />
        <forward name="validUser" path="/welcome.jsp" />
        <forward name="loginPage" path="/login.jsp" />
        <forward name="newApp" path="/newApplication.do" />
        <forward name="migrateStudent" path="/LoginByPassAction.do" />
        <forward name="selectProg" path="/selectProgram.jsp" />
    </action>
```

I am trying to solve the error from couple of hours but haven't got any success. 
What can be the cause of this error, how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
<form-beans>
<form-bean name="myLoginForm" type="com.dps.onlineAdmissions.form.MyLoginForm"/>
</form-beans>
```

not `form-beam` in the tag. Correct the spelling mistake

Comment: oh damn. yeah right. Thank you so much for saving me!